# Default taxonomy template in plugin, override in theme

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, templates, template-redirect

Building off of [this question/answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12295/creating-a-default-custom-post-template-that-a-theme-can-override), I've sucessfully implemented the `single` view for my custom post types, but I'd also like to offer the same thing for taxonomies. I've looked through the docs and thought that [is_taxonomy()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_taxonomy) would be perfect for filtering out exactly what taxonomy I'm on, but that's deprecated --> and it's replacement, [taxonomy_exists()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/taxonomy_exists), doesn't necessarily seem like it would fit the bill.

So, first question is, can I do the same thing for taxonomies as single-posts described in the question I referenced? (I'm using his question edit solution currently). And secondly, is `is_taxonomy` the way to go here?

Really appreciate any insight. Thanks!

**Update:** Is [query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/19415/9605) the best way to check for the taxonomy?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Taxonomy in plugin and template](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50201/custom-taxonomy-in-plugin-and-template)

Comment: It's not clear what you want `is_taxonomy`/`taxonomy_exists` for. They both (the former depreciated) checked if a taxonomy had been registered. Maybe you are after if the a taxonomy page is being requested? [`is_tag()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tag)

Comment: Yup - `is_tax()` was exactly what I was looking for -if you want to re-submit that as an answer I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I ended up using (for all those interested):

```
    function override_tax_template($template){
        // is a specific custom taxonomy being shown?
        $taxonomy_array = array('tax1','tax2');
        foreach ($taxonomy_array as $taxonomy_single) {
            if ( is_tax($taxonomy_single) ) {
                if(file_exists(trailingslashit(get_stylesheet_directory()) . 'tax-template-directory/taxonomy-'.$taxonomy_single.'.php')) {
                    $template = trailingslashit(get_stylesheet_directory()) . 'tax-template-directory/taxonomy-'.$taxonomy_single.'.php';
                }
                else {
                    $template = BASE_PLUGIN_DIR . 'includes/tax-template-directory/taxonomy-'.$taxonomy_single.'.php';
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return $template;
    }
    add_filter('template_include','override_tax_template');
```

I hooked into `template_include` to check if there was a file in the active template called `taxonomy-YOUR-TAXONOMY-NAME.php` and if not, loads the default from your plugin.